# trying to connect to DB2 using cloud connectors through PCF

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-connectors

I am trying to connect to DB2 using Spring Cloud Connectors through PCF but my DB2 is 2-way SSL. Can any one tell me how I can configure SSL using Spring Cloud Connectors?

Normally i use like this without Spring Cloud Connectors

```
DB2SimpleDataSource dataSource = new DB2SimpleDataSource(); //NOSONAR

    dataSource.setUser(userName);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
    dataSource.setServerName(server);
    dataSource.setPortNumber(Integer.parseInt(port));
    dataSource.setDatabaseName(name);
    dataSource.setDriverType(4);
    dataSource.setSslConnection(true);
    dataSource.setSslTrustStoreLocation("keystore/pas_ist_db.jks");
    dataSource.setSslTrustStorePassword(sslPassword);
```

Comment: Are the values for the SSL parameters (`TrustStoreLocation`, `TrustStorePassword`) provided in the service binding credentials (i.e. in VCAP_SERVICES), or do those values come from somewhere else?

Comment: Those are from VCAP_SERVICES , but how cloud connectors will pick ? if i use                                                                                            
 cloudFactory.getCloud().getServiceConnector(dbServiceName, DataSource.class, dataSourceConfig);

Comment: Connectors won't pick those up, because it isn't aware that those are valid fields in the credentials for a service. What DB2 service broker builds those credentials? Can you post an example of VCAP_SERVICES with those fields in it? You can also create an issue at https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-connectors/issues with the details of VCAP_SERVICES.